# Difference of continuous cdf and absolute continuous cdf

Tags: real-analysis, statistics

What's the difference of these two things?
Is it only about the property of the cdf itself?
I Googled it, but not satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

1. A cdf being continuous means that for every $a\in\mathbb R$, $P(X=a)=0$.
2. A cdf being absolutely continuous means that the distribution is described by a  pdf: that is, there exists a nonnegative function $g$ such that for every $a\le b$ in $\mathbb R$, $P(a\le X\le b)=\int_a^b g$.

2 implies 1 but not the other way around. The [Cantor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) is a counterexample.